# Echo div class after form is submitted

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form on my website. When a user presses submit with their details filled it, it sends me an email. However, when they click submit, a green box should appear below `<div class="sent-message">` yet, when I click submit, it shows a red box and says, "mail sent". Here are the PHP lines in contact.php that are causing this...

Simply, the box should be changed to green and have the text from sent-message instead of this.

```
if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "mail sent";
}
else {
    echo "mail sent failed";
}
```

```html
<div class="form">


  <form action="contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="loading">Loading</div>
      <div class="error-message"></div>
      <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" title="Send Message">Send Message</button></div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
!(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $('form.php-email-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs
     
      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;

    var this_form = $(this);
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    if( ! action ) {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html('The form action property is not set!');
      return false;
    }
    
    this_form.find('.sent-message').slideUp();
    this_form.find('.error-message').slideUp();
    this_form.find('.loading').slideDown();

    if ( $(this).data('recaptcha-site-key') ) {
      var recaptcha_site_key = $(this).data('recaptcha-site-key');
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_site_key, {action: 'php_email_form_submit'}).then(function(token) {
          php_email_form_submit(this_form,action,this_form.serialize() + '&recaptcha-response=' + token);
        });
      });
    } else {
      php_email_form_submit(this_form,action,this_form.serialize());
    }
    
    return true;
  });

  function php_email_form_submit(this_form, action, data) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: data,
      timeout: 40000
    }).done( function(msg){
      if (msg == 'OK') {
        this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
        this_form.find('.sent-message').slideDown();
        this_form.find("input:not(input[type=submit]), textarea").val('');
      } else {
        this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
        if(!msg) {
          msg = 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action + '<br>';
        }
        this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(msg);
      }
    }).fail( function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var error_msg = "Form submission failed!<br>";
      if(data.statusText || data.status) {
        error_msg += 'Status:';
        if(data.statusText) {
          error_msg += ' ' + data.statusText;
        }
        if(data.status) {
          error_msg += ' ' + data.status;
        }
        error_msg += '<br>';
      }
      if(data.responseText) {
        error_msg += data.responseText;
      }
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(error_msg);
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It depends on how are you submitting the form. Put your code showing the same. And the PHP code you have put above belongs to `contact.php` ?

Comment: the form is set to POST and yes, the PHP code above belongs to contact.php the rest of the code in contact.php is for sending the email @mPareek

Comment: Where is the "red box" in your html?

Comment: in index.html `<div class="error-message">` @mPareek

Comment: You could do something like this: `$sent = false; if($mail->Send()) { $sent = true; }` Then in your html you show message: `<?php if($sent) { ?><div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div><?php } ?> `

Comment: Can you please put this as an answer? @mPareek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, in contact.php:

```
$sent = false; 
if($mail->Send()) { $sent = true; }
```

Then in your html you show message:

```
<?php 
if($sent) { ?>
<div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**UPDATE**

So your form submission is controlled by jQuery. You can show message by just `echo 'OK'` instead of "mail sent" in your php script

Comment: Where in the HTML file would I put the second script? Remember, it is a .html file so it does not support PHP @mPareek

Comment: You haven't mentioned about .html anywhere in your question.  How are you displaying the "mail sent" message then?

Comment: I apologies for the confusion, i hope that cleared it up. @mPareek

Comment: I have found the jQuery that controls it. Please check update

Comment: Yes, so this is what I asked in first place that how are you submitting the form. So, that means you are using jquery and ajax.

Comment: Yes, I apologise. I couldn't find it

Comment: Thank you kindly, apologies for my lack of experience in this field. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

```
if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "mail sent";
    $color = 'green';
}
else {
    echo "mail sent failed";
    $color = 'red';
}
?>


    <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="loading">Loading</div>
      <div class="error-message"></div>
      <div class="sent-message" style='background-color:"<?php echo $color;' ?>">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue, it still shows a red box that says mail sent @Namys

Comment: @slkdanfalvsd explain better. Where this message is displayed? In which `div`? Check you css? Did div with class sent-message have some css properties?

Comment: The div class is in index.html and the form is contact.php.

The styles for div class="sent-message" is in my css file. Im not sure why you would need the css though... @pLe0mAx

Comment: @slkdanfalvsd Because ovbiously in your css have some css property that rewrite this and your font color stays RED. Inspect it or explain better where you print your message. Try to set `!important` to this `style='background-color:"<?php echo $color;' ?> !important"`

Comment: I will update and add the CSS for sent-message, error-message and loading

Comment: I tried adding `!important` and it still gives me a red box with "mail sent" @pLe0mAx

Comment: `echo '<div style='background-color:green">mail sent</div>';`

Comment: This creates green highlighted text inside the red box. @pLe0mAx

Comment: Your div with that color is `div class="error-message"` so your message is printed there. Check where your message is printed or give more informations how you print it. May be some ajax? Jquery? It cannot be just `echo`

Comment: I'm not sure why it is echoing using `div class="error-message"`

Comment: Would it be useful if i posted more of index.html or contact.php? @pLe0mAx

Comment: Do you have the project online? Or it's on localhost? I asked how you echo the result? Ajax?

Comment: I have found the jQuery that controls it. Please check update @pLe0mAx

Answer (score 0):

Your code must return

```
if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

and if you want differen message, you can change it here:

```
<div class="sent-message">My new message</div>
```